# Изменение отображения DateTime в разных платформах в одной культуре C#

Tags: c#, строки, datetime, format

Есть код, который извлекает наименование месяца со строгим заданием культуры CultureInfo("ru-RU")

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));
```

Совершенно случайно наткнулись на такую ситуацию, что данный код возвращает разную информацию на разных платформах (к примеру, на .net core 3.1 и .net 6 (Август и август))

В моём понимании то, как отображается текст задан в культуре и не должен меняться при переходе от одной платформе к другой, как так вышло, что формат изменился? И есть у кого-нибудь информация о том, как и когда это произошло?

Comment: Скорее всего, это произошло в .NET 5 при переходе от NLS к ICU. Ссылки: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu), [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization#nls), [4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/6.0/culture-creation-invariant-mode)